# LinkageError en Websphere (IIOMetadata.getAsTree)

Tags: java, java-ee, websphere, constraints

Tengo una aplicación web montada en un Websphere, en la cual hago unos exportar a excel utilizando la mítica librería poi. Y me salta un error de Linkage al momento de ejecutar la siguiente sentencia, es justamente en la linea del pict.resize();

```
 Picture pict = drawing.createPicture(anchor, pictureIdx);
 // ajustar imagen al ancho de las columnas
 pict.resize(1.084018264840183D); //linea problemática
```

El error que produce es el siguiente:

```
java.lang.LinkageError: loading constraint violation when resolving method "javax/imageio/metadata/IIOMetadata.getAsTree(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/w3c/dom/Node;" : loader "com/ibm/ws/classloader/CompoundClassLoader@a60f1997" of class "org/apache/poi/ss/util/ImageUtils" and loader "com/ibm/oti/vm/BootstrapClassLoader@123472f2" of class "javax/imageio/metadata/IIOMetadata" have different types for the method signature
at org.apache.poi.ss.util.ImageUtils.getResolution(ImageUtils.java:106)
at org.apache.poi.ss.util.ImageUtils.getImageDimension(ImageUtils.java:68)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFPicture.getImageDimension(XSSFPicture.java:278)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFPicture.getPreferredSize(XSSFPicture.java:203)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFPicture.resize(XSSFPicture.java:170)
```

Entiendo que es un problema de las librerías que esta cargando el classloader, pero no consigo identificar cual, tengo claro que el método problemático es "IIOMetadata.getAsTree()", que me dice que esta declarado de manera diferente en las clases ImageUtils (de poi.jar) y IIOMetadata (de rt.jar que es del sdk).

Comment: Que librerías importas? porque la IIOMetadata si que tiene el método getAsTree() pero en la librería ImageUtils no lo he visto

Comment: Importo poi org.apache.poi 3.10.1, yo veo que en ImageUtils hace una referencia a getAsTree():

`Element node = (Element)r.getImageMetadata(0).getAsTree("javax_imageio_1.0");`